# блокировка события родительского элемента при нажатии на дочерний

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте!
есть таблица:

```
                 <tr name="tables" id="'.$index.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal2" onclick="pendingSMS('.$index.'); alert(1);">
                    <td>'.$index.'</td>
                    <td>'.$smsCount.'</td>
                    <td>'.$numCount.'</td>
                    <td>'.date("d.m.Y H:i:s", $createTime).'</td>
                    <td>'.$perAmount.' смс в '.$perMinutes.' мин</td>
                    <td>'.$sender.'</td>
                    <td>'.$message.'</td>
                    <td>'.date("d.m.Y H:i:s", $startSend).'</td>
                    <td>'.date("d.m.Y H:i:s", $endSend).'</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs active" onclick="StopSend('.$index.', 1);">Stop</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal" onclick="EditSend('.$index.')">Edit</button>
                    '.$pauseBtn.'
                </tr>
```

в ней есть кнопки. так вот при нажатии на колонку таблицы, выводится модальное окно, и при нажатии на кнопку выводится модальное окно, но уже другое. но проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает событие родителя и открывается два модальных окна. пробовал колхозным методом ставил флаг mouseover и mouseout на кнопке. было все ок, но сейчас эта таблица еще и обновляется каждые 300 миллисекунд, и колхозный метод не работает... что можно еще придумать?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation`

Comment: @Igor, знаю я эту функцию, но толку то... сначала срабатывает событие родителя, потом уже дочернего элемента, короче куда я ее не пихал, результата нужного не добился

Comment: я думаю, Вы ошибаетесь по вопросу о порядке событий https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Comment: @Igor, может быть... я так решил т.к. повешал alert по клику на дочерний и родительский, при клике на дочерний сначала выскакивает алерт родителя затем дочернего.

Comment: @Igor, ставлю event.stopPropagation на onclick по кнопке в итоге вообще ни одного окна нет. куда еще мне его запихнуть хз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation`

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr name="tables" id="'.$index.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal2" onclick="alert('click on Row');">
    <td>'.$index.'</td>
    <td>'.$smsCount.'</td>
    <td>'.$numCount.'</td>
    <td>'.$sender.'</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs active"
        onclick="event.stopPropagation();alert('click on Stop');">Stop</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal" 
        onclick="alert('click on Edit')">Edit</button>
    '.$pauseBtn.'
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: да так то оно так, но открытие модального окна прячется где-то в глубинах бутстрапа... т.е. строки
`data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-modal1"` обеспечивают открытие модального окна и когда я на онклик привязываю event.stopPropagation(); то модальное окно не всплывает...

Comment: все получилось, спасибо за пример. покопавшись более глубоко, порывшись в глубинах бутстрапа был для меня открыт способ вызова модального окна методами jquery и все получилось и не без `event.stopPropagation`, спасибо)